# The best way to document python code

Tags: python, autodoc

I'm starting to work on documentation of python33 modules. But I'm beginner in this field.
I will be very grateful if you will help me to choose good instrument to do this.
I read a lot of topics in Internet. I've fount that the most popular are sphinx and Epydoc. But which of them is better to use? Almost all problems discussed in the Internet are quite old. I'm sure that situation is changed since 2011 year.. May be somebody is pro in doing docs for python docs. Please help to make first steps.

Answer (score 5):

Cannot imagine more useful and helpful material except:

- [PEP8 Comments section](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments)
- [PEP8 Documentation Strings section](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings)
- [Documentation](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/documentation.html) thread of [The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/)

And, yes:

> Epydoc is discontinued. Use Sphinx instead.

Hope that helps.